# Duplicate class error when trying to add firebase dependencies in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm trying to develop an app in AndroidStudio and i'm using cloud firestore as database. I'm having some issues when i try to add both `'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.11.0'`and `'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0` dependencies. I get these messages when I try to make the project:

```
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.FirebaseAppLifecycleListener found in modules firebase-admin-6.11.0.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.11.0) and firebase-common-18.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:18.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.FirebaseException found in modules firebase-admin-6.11.0.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.11.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions found in modules firebase-admin-6.11.0.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.11.0) and firebase-common-18.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:18.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$1 found in modules firebase-admin-6.11.0.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.11.0) and firebase-common-18.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:18.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions$Builder found in modules firebase-admin-6.11.0.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.11.0) and firebase-common-18.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:18.0.0)
Duplicate class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId found in modules firebase-admin-6.11.0.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.11.0) and firebase-iid-19.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:19.0.0)
```

`Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.`

I have tried with some other versions, older and newer but got the same problem. Anybody has any idea how to solve this? Thanks a lot. Here's my app gradle code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "br.com.valorinveste.nextmobilefx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties'
        }
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

and the project gradle code

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: firebase-admin is not meant for use in Android apps.  It's for backend code.

Comment: Your error message is telling you that the same class exists in more than one JAR file and each JAR file is associated with a different module. And it looks like these JAR files are third party JARs and not yours, so I'm guessing you are either using non-modular JARs or perhaps you are using CLASSPATH rather than `module-path`.